# Getting Max ID from core data & sqlite

Tags: ios, core-data, max

I have a table Users and have bunch of columns in the core data model. One of the column is user_id and I am trying to get the highest user_id and add + 1 to it and pass it to the next object that will be inserted. I followed [apple developer guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CoreDataSnippets/Articles/fetchExpressions.html) and implemented as suggested. Here is the code that I am trying to execute.

Issue is : My account_id value that is being returned is being set to some weird number which even doesn't exists in the database.

**"account_id" = 139784529;**  It is supposed to be 1 since I only have saved in core data.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Users" inManagedObjectContext:self._managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

// Specify that the request should return dictionaries.
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

// Create an expression for the key path.
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"account_id"];

// Create an expression to represent the function you want to apply
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:"
                                                     arguments:@[keyPathExpression]];

// Create an expression description using the minExpression and returning a date.
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];

// The name is the key that will be used in the dictionary for the return value.
[expressionDescription setName:@"maxAccountId"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:expression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSInteger32AttributeType]; // For example, NSDateAttributeType

// Set the request's properties to fetch just the property represented by the expressions.
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[expressionDescription]];

// Execute the fetch.
NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [self._managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (objects == nil) {
    // Handle the error.
}
else {
    if ([objects count] > 0) {
        nextAccountId = [[[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"maxAccountId"] integerValue];
    }
}
}

@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[exception reason]);
}

return nextAccountId + 1;
```

Hope someone faced this issue before and fixed it.

Thank you

Comment: The value that you see looks like a "normal" garbage value that you get from accessing uninitialized variables. Setting `nextAccountId` to zero should fix that. I am not sure why `[objects count]` returns zero, though.

Comment: [objects count] does not return zero. I am not sure what you are referring to ?

Comment: It does not look like there is an assignment of `nextAccountId` in some paths, specifically when count is zero. Daniel's answer below added an `else` to cover that.

Comment: thank you for the comment. I just looked into my code and noticed, I do have the variable initialized.     NSInteger nextAccountId = 0;

And the thing is, the value [[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"maxAccountId"] integerValue]; itself is giving me that junk value.

Comment: +1 Very nice question. Is the issue fixed, I tried out a sample project with your issue. But for me it worked great.

Comment: @Anupdas, yes the issue has been fixed. See the answer below. Thank you for looking at it.

Comment: Good to know that you fixed it. Your question actually gave a new way of find top object. Till now I have been doing a fetch limited to size one and sorted in descending order to find the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you all for taking a look at the question. Also thank you for the comments and answers.  After figuring out the problem viewing sqlite database from the terminal, I noticed the table was corrupted and it was giving all junk values back to me. The issue was really simple. This is what I have done to fix it.

1. Deleted the app from the iPhone Simulator.
2. Clean solution
3. re compiled the program. Ran it, and bam.. it worked.

Just a developer tip for those who did not know about **accessing sqlite from terminal**.

1. Figure out the location to your sqlite. Usually
   /User/UserName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/xxxxxxxxxx/Documents
   cd to this directory.
2. type sqlite3 command
3. attach "Application.sqlite" as db1
4. bam.. run your commands.
5. If you want to look at the databases running within - type .database

Thank you all once again.

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine for me after I removed the try/catch code and simplified the if statement after the fetch request to this:

```
if ([objects count] > 0) {
    nextAccountId = [[[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"maxAccountId"] integerValue];
}
else {
    nextAccountId = 0;
}
```

If that doesn't fix it confirm that you have the correct initialized managed object context (`self._managedObjectContext` vs. `self.managedObjectContext` depending how you defined it) and the entity/attribute names are correct.

Comment: thank you for the response, I am going to try this and let you know how it worked.

Comment: I tried what you said and it still gives me the same issue. Attaching the log, in the comment

(lldb) po objects
$12 = 0x08156790 <_PFArray 0x8156790>(
{
    maxAccountId = 139784529;
}
)